# gnuplot: How can I add vertical grid line only at midnight every day when using a time xscale?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I add vertical grid line only at midnight every day when using a time xscale in gnuplot? I want to be able to produce multiple plots with different time spans from 24-hours to 2-months. I want to put a vertical grid line at midnight every day on the graph so I can easily distinguish individual days on the graph. This is what my gnuplot script looks like now:

```
set terminal png size 900, 300
set output "images/temps.png"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"
set datafile separator ","
set ylabel "Temperature \260F"
set xlabel "Time"
set grid ytics
set y2tics mirror
set y2label "Temperature \260F"
set grid xtics lc rgb "#888888" lw 1 lt 0
plot [:][:] 'data.csv' using 1:2 title "" with lines
```

With this script, I get vertical grids added at automatic intervals. Those intervals are meaningful intervals, but I want to be able to force the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer:

```
set xtics 86400
```

This is in seconds. 86400 seconds in 24 hours.

Comment: The one problem this presents it that it restricts displaying tic values at the bottom to this interval. For shorter graphs (<= 3 days), this is not what I want.

I think what I want then is to just place a regular vertical line that is not a tic mark.